# Rails I18n fallbacks for hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have the following `locale/*.yml` files:

```
en:
  hello:
    world: World
    time:
      am: "AM"
      pm: "PM"

ja:
  hello:
    world:
    time:
      am: "午前"
      pm: "午後"
```

Fallback working well when I'm trying to call missing locale:

```
I18n.locale = :ja
I18n.t('hello.world') => 'World'
```

But it returns 'nil' on some values when I'm calling for parent key (`hello`):

```
I18n.locale = :ja
I18n.t('hello') => { world: nil, time: { am: "午前", pm: "午後" } }
```

How can I get translations with fallbacks: `{ world: 'World', time: { am: "午前", pm: "午後" } }`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to call the translate method with the `:default => ''` option?

Comment: like this? `I18n.t('hello', default: "")` - the same result

Comment: Sorry, you are trying to get the fallback anyways, not an empty string, my bad.

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for. I wanted to fallback with the key if the translation wasn't present.
`I18n.t(some_key, scope: [:users, :permissions], default: some_key)`

Answer (score 1):

The fallback works when a key does not exist in a locale. The problem here is that `hello` exists.

I've come across the same requirement. What I've ended up doing is apply the fallbacks at load time rather than at runtime as follows:

```
I18n::Backend::Simple.prepend(Module.new do
  def init_translations
    super

    # Can't do anything if fallbacks haven't loaded yet.
    return unless I18n.respond_to?(:fallbacks)

    merged = {}
    available_locales.each do |base|
      ::I18n.fallbacks[base].reverse.each do |fallback|
        merged[base] ||= {}
        merged[base].deep_merge!(@translations[fallback] || {})
      end
    end

    @translations = merged
  end
end)
```